# Installing rubypython ruby gem on mac m1

Tags: ruby, rubypython

We recently upgraded to Mac M1 and trying to install rubypython gem.

https://github.com/halostatue/rubypython/blob/master/rubypython.gemspec

As per the gem specification, it only allows FFI version of 1.0.x

```
s.add_dependency(%q<ffi>, ["~> 1.0.7"])
```

The problem is 1.0.x ffi version doesn't install on mac m1. We are only able to install ffi 1.15.4 on mac m1. Is there any way to install rubypython on mac m1